# External Javascript file that has events for a Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jquery-events

Is there a correct way of reading a Kendo Event from an external Javascript file?

On my view, **.cshtml**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
        .Name("EmployeeGrid")
        .Columns(cols => { })
        .Events(evt => evt.DataBound("afterGridLoaded"))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                                    .Batch(true)
                                    .PageSize(10)
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetEmployeeList", "EmployeeDetail"))
                                   )
      )
```

The **"afterGridLoaded"** is sitting in an external Javascript that is loaded on the top of the page.

**External JavaScript File** -

```
$(function () {
  function afterGridLoaded(e) {
  $(".k-button.xxx").click(function () {
    debugger;
    var idEmployee = $(this).attr('tag');
    myJsFunc(idEmployee);
    });
  }
});
```

**And the way the Javascript is called** - This is done at the top of the page

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/Views/EmployeeDetail/EmployeeList.js" ></script>    
}
```

The external Javascript file is loaded as I can see it on the DEV tools in Chrome under the network tab,

[image: External Javascript loaded]

When I try to load the page I get the following error message on the console which prevents the page from loading further,

[image: Error message]

Is there a way to get the kendo event to work using the external Javascript file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `afterGridLoaded` function is wrapped around `jQuery` Closure function, which means you can't call it from outside the closure.

Remove the closure and move the script tag to the bottom of your page

```
// $(function () { get rid of this
function afterGridLoaded(e) {
    $(".k-button.xxx").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var idEmployee = $(this).attr('tag');
        myJsFunc(idEmployee);
    });
}
//}); and this
```